# SnailSVN 'remains conflict'

Tags: svn

anyone tried using SnailSVN app on Mac OS? when I tried to commit my CreateItem.xml it says 'remains in conflict' , I already tried everything from deleting the file file in SVN to deleting my local file and it still says 'remains in conflict', my other files commits with no problem, only the CreateItem.xml has problem.

[image]

Comment: More appropriate for [superuser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: Is there an actual SVN conflict or it's a bogus error message?

Comment: Did you actually mark the conflict resolved with `svn resolve` or are you just messing around with the file?

Comment: I just deleted my file and hit update.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the files in the SnailSVN commit window and select "`Resolved...`".

You may also copy the files to another location, revert the changes, copy back the files and then commit the changes.

Comment: the right click -> resolved doesn't work for me for some reason :(

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this myself and the solution for me was to open up the terminal and navigate to my repository.  I then ran the following command:

```
svn resolve
```

Which responded with:

*Tree conflict on 'Path/To/Conflict/'*

*local dir delete, incoming dir delete or move upon update*

In the options presented I entered **r**, mark resolved.

I was then able to commit and not see the missing file, in my case, nor get the message you received in your screenshot.

The option '*Resolved...*' was not available to me through the SnailSVN GUI Commit dialog.